# How to put array on loop multiple circle?

Tags: javascript, html

I have try to draw multple circle with for. it works , but now i want to put array in a "for" part.

```
function draw_circle (circleX, circleY, radius, fill) { 
      context.fillStyle = "black";
      context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 300);

      context.strokeStyle = "red";
      context.strokeRect(5, 5, 790, 290);

      context.fillStyle = fill;
      context.arc(circleX, circleY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
      context.fill();
 }

 function draw_multiple() {
      var i;
      var circles = []; // How to put array so this code will work with array?
      for(i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
      draw_circle ((i*70)+100,100, 30 , "cyan");
      }
 }

 draw_multiple();
```

Comment: -1, not a very clear question. What do you want to put into the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to call draw_circle for multiple circles and circles information would be in array. If that is the case then check the code snippet below:

Here, we have created a circle class which will hold all the properties like origin, radius, fill color etc. We can create instances of this class and add them in array to have a circles collection. We also have a draw method in circle class so that circle can draw itself. Now, in our drawCircles method we have added circles in collection and passed parameters in circles constructor. Now, we can call draw method on all objects in collection. You can also separate the object creation and drawing logic based upon when you want to perform these actions e.g. say on page load or in some ajax call you have got the circle information. Then you can add them to collection may be singelton or global collection based upon how you want to manage things. I would not suggest global variable though. You can then associate drawCircle method with some control event like button click etc.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

//my circle class
var Circle = function(circleX, circleY, radius, color){

    this.circleX = circleX;
    this.circleY = circleY;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;

    this.draw = function(canvasId){
        var c = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.circleX, this.circleY, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
    };
};


//my onclick draw function
function drawCenterdCircles(){        
    var circles = [];

    circles.push(new Circle(100,75,50,"black"));
    circles.push(new Circle(100,75,55,"red"));
    circles.push(new Circle(100,75,60,"green"));
    circles.push(new Circle(100,75,65,"yellow"));
    //add more circles
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        circles[i].draw("centerdCircles");   
    }    
}

function drawSeparatedCircles(){        
    var circles = [];

    circles.push(new Circle(100,75,50,"black"));
    circles.push(new Circle(205,75,50,"red"));
    circles.push(new Circle(310,75,50,"green"));
    circles.push(new Circle(415,75,50,"yellow"));
    //add more circles
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
        circles[i].draw("separateCircles");   
    }    
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="centerdCircles" width="600" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<br>
<input type="button" value="Draw Centerd Circles" onclick="drawCenterdCircles();"/>
<br>
<canvas id="separateCircles" width="600" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<br>

<input type="button" value="Draw Separated Circles" onclick="drawSeparatedCircles();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, sorry for my bad question before. I want to draw 10 circles in horizontal line and each circle draw with array. and for the first circle coordinates, radius, and fill, i call them with my draw_circle function. and X coordinates for the second - tenth circles ++ in loop. So the circles will like this -> o o o o o . Thank you and sorry for uncorrect spells

Comment: Do you want to create instance of circle (above) in loop? You want to add specific distance between them, right?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I don't know how to put array for my each circle.

Comment: Thank you so much Anuj Yadav , you helped me alot :) .  I will learn part by part of this code, especially the array part ! Thank You!!

Comment: Glad I could help. I will recommend you to read some programming books as array, loops etc concepts that you need to use in even simplest of programs.

Comment: Yes, Im looking for the e-book now. Thank you :)

Comment: If the answer was helpful can you please accept that.